# PHP(via IIS 7.5) não esta recebendo post via ajax

Tags: php, ajax, iis

Tenho uma requisição AJAX feita para a própria página onde a rotina AJAX foi definida.

Configurando a requisição com método POST, não está sendo enviado. Alterando para GET, é enviado com sucesso.

Creio que isso possa ser alguma configuração no IIS ou na instalação do PHP. Ambos estão instalados localmente e há poucos dias foram feita alterações neles devido a erros que depois foram descobertos ser no banco de dados, mas não não sei exatamente o que foi alterado.

Esse é o código que estou utilizando:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async: true,
    url: "nova_pg_novo_grupo.php?t=" + d.getTime(),
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: {
        "comando" : "salvarGrupo",
        "inputNomeGrupo" : $("#inputNomeGrupo").val()
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
       alert(data);
        $("#divSuccess").html("Grupo salvo!");
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert(xhr.status);
        alert(thrownError);
    }
});
```

Antes também não era necessário declarar o *ContentType* e agorase não declarar apresenta internal Server Error (500).

Edit: Acho que descobri o problema, o php não está exibindo erros... Obrigado

Comment: Como os dados são tratados no PHP?

Comment: Não está sendo enviado ou não está sendo recebido? Você pode verificar no Dev Tools do browser e ver se a requisição foi feita. Sabendo isso pode-se buscar o erro no local correto (JS or PHP ou IIS)

Comment: Através do código como passei, no _alert_ é retornado todo o conteudo html, pulando _if_ do PHP, mudando para get, o _alert_ retorna que foram pegas as variaveis enviadas. Mas anteriormente, com mesma versão do javascript, ocorria tudo certo, eu escrevia meus codigos da mesma forma, o que me leva a pensar ser no PHP ou IIS que tiveram suas configurações alteradas (não fui eu que mudei e não sei configura-los), no php, para teste eu coloquei esse codigo:
    if ($_POST['comando']){
        echo "post";
    }
    if ($_GET['comando']){
        echo "get";
    }


Desculpe a má edição...